# How to resolve problem with integer dates from excel file SSIS

Tags: c#, date, ssis

The issue is in problem to converting date from excel integer format to `db_date ("yyyy-MM-dd")`. The convertion trick with datestamp from `1899` doesn't work - on data viewer at the output, I have a null value. I using old Visual Studio `2008` with `SSIS` package editor.

I' ve tried derived block column and convert it via Expression field. I have a solution in script transformation task but I think this is too complicated to use that solution. I used a lot of solution from this and other site forums. Nothing works instead of my solution borrowed from somebody from here.

I expect format date from integer `43613` to format for inserting it to database `yyyy-MM-dd`.

I' ve tried derived block column and convert it via Expression field. I have a solution in script transformation task but I think this is too complicated to use that solution. I tested a lot of solutions from this and other site forums. Nothing works instead of my solution borrowed from somebody from here.

Comment: Hi, please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [StackOverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Please show what you've done.

Comment: I have read the help page, but this problem is connected to not to write code. This task is connected to with ssis package editor not with programming. I have used this code to avoid problems - but the date will stay as string ;/ https://pastebin.com/N3FxWRuB

Comment: If a solution works, then perhaps it is not too complicated. Please edit the question and share the solution you have.

Comment: Excel (by default) uses the 1900 date system. This simply means that the date 1 Jan 1900 has a true numeric value of 1, 2 Jan 1900 has a value of 2 etc. These values are called "serial values" in Excel and it is these serial values that allows us to use dates in calculations.  Just use the DATEADD function in a derived column to convert.   Something like DATEADD("dd", <<ExcelValueHere>>  -2 , (DT_DBTIMESTAMP) "1900-01-01").   You have to subtract 2 because of https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year